# UIActivityIndicatorView display in the center of the screen

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode4

Is there a way to have the UIActivityIndicatorView display in the center of the screen to mirror the NetworkActivityIndicator?  So I want the same process as the NetworkActivityIndicator, just with a larger indicator that will be more noticeable to the user.

Answer (score 27):

Try this:

```
UIView *view = /* whatever your main view is */
UIActivityIndicatorView *spinner = [[UIActivityIndicatorVIew alloc] 
            initWithActivityIndicatorStyle:UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleWhiteLarge];
CGRect frame = spinner.frame;
frame.origin.x = view.frame.size.width / 2 - frame.size.width / 2;
frame.origin.y = view.frame.size.height / 2 - frame.size.height / 2;
spinner.frame = frame;
[view addSubview:spinner];
[spinner startAnimating];
[spinner release]; // Or, you could keep a handle to this for later to stop animating it
```

This basically centers the spinner in its enclosing view, whatever that might be.

If you do not keep a handle to spinner, and if spinner is the only subview of view (or at least in a well known position), you could later get a handle to it by dipping into `[view subviews]` for it.

EDIT: You could also probably use `CGRectGetMidX()` and `CGRectGetMidY()` instead of the more complicated equations above for finding `x` and `y`... Your mileage may vary. :-)

**EDIT** (2/25/2016)

This answer has received some up-votes recently, so I thought an update was in order. There is actually an even better way to do this now. This example places a `UIActivityIndicatorView` in the center of a `UITableView`.

```
self.spinner = [[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc] initWithActivityIndicatorStyle:UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleGray];
_spinner.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
_spinner.hidesWhenStopped = YES;
[self.tableView addSubview:self.spinner];

[self.tableView addConstraints:@[
                                 [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:_spinner
                                                              attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterX
                                                              relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                                                 toItem:self.tableView
                                                              attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterX
                                                             multiplier:1 constant:0],
                                 [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:_spinner
                                                              attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterY
                                                              relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                                                 toItem:self.tableView
                                                              attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterY
                                                             multiplier:1 constant:0]
                                 ]];
```

Comment: May i know how can i add text along with UIActivityIndicatorView

Comment: You could create a `UILabel`, add it to your view, then use constraints to say, center it below the spinner. You might use a visual constraint format like `"V:[spinner]-[label]"` and `NSLayoutFormatAlignAllCenterX`.

Answer (score 23):

This works for me inside a UIViewController:

```
override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
    activityIndicator.center = view.center
}
```

Answer (score 9):

```
indicatorView.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleBottomMargin|UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleTopMargin|UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleLeftMargin|UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleRightMargin;
indicatorView.center = self.view.center;
```

Answer (score 3):

```
activityInd.center = CGPointMake(160,240);
```

Comment: I think you mean it only good for iPhone. Its better if it can be written like `activityInd.center = CGPointMake(self.view.bounds.size.width / 2.0, self.view.bounds.size.height / 2.0);` but i'm still gonna give +1 because center is imo better than setting frame for this particular purpose.

Comment: Yups, I was only talking about iPhone.

Answer (score 1):

```
-(void)setCenter:(UIView*)view{
UIActivityIndicatorView *actView = [[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc]initWithActivityIndicatorStyle:UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleWhite];
[view addSubview:actView];
[actView startAnimating];
CGSize boundsSize = view.bounds.size;
CGRect frameToCenter = actView.frame;
// center horizontally
if (frameToCenter.size.width < boundsSize.width)
    frameToCenter.origin.x = (boundsSize.width - frameToCenter.size.width) / 2;
else
    frameToCenter.origin.x = 0;

// center vertically
if (frameToCenter.size.height < boundsSize.height)
    frameToCenter.origin.y = (boundsSize.height - frameToCenter.size.height) / 2;
else
    frameToCenter.origin.y = 0;

actView.frame = frameToCenter;
```

}

Comment: just pass the view in this function it will take care all the things :)

Answer (score 1):

In Swift:

```
var activityIndicator = UIActivityIndicatorView(activityIndicatorStyle: UIActivityIndicatorViewStyle.Gray)

override func viewDidLoad() {
    activityIndicator.hidesWhenStopped = true;
    activityIndicator.activityIndicatorViewStyle  = UIActivityIndicatorViewStyle.Gray;
    activityIndicator.center = view.center;
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}
```

For more information refer the below tutorial:

http://sourcefreeze.com/uiactivityindicatorview-example-using-swift-in-ios/

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me. Notice I use bounds rather than frame. The frame properly doesn't always show the rect based on the orientation (this method goes inside the view controller).

```
- (void) viewDidLayoutSubviews
{
    if (self.spinner)
    {
        CGRect screenRect = self.view.bounds;

        self.spinner.frame = CGRectMake(roundf((screenRect.size.width - 50) * 0.5f),
                                        roundf((screenRect.size.height - 50) * 0.5f),
                                        50,
                                        50);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Only this work perfect for me, simple and fast:

```
UIActivityIndicatorView *spinner = [[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc] initWithActivityIndicatorStyle:UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleGray]; 

spinner.center = CGPointMake(self.view.frame.size.width/2, self.view.frame.size.height/2);

[self.view addSubview:spinner]; 
[spinner startAnimating];
```

Answer (score 0):

in swift 2.0 xcode 7:

```
 override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
    self.Loader.center = self.view.center
 }
```